# If $\sigma$ is a cycle of length $r$, then it has order $r$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I should specify that $\sigma \in S_n$, the symmetric group. I've written down some permutations and it seems like their order correspond to their lengths. How can I prove this? I was thinking of using induction, but I can't seem to write a cycle with length $r$ into disjoint cycles and thus unable to use the result that disjoint cycles commutes.

Edit: WLOG, I assume $\sigma = (1,2,3,...,r)$. I observed that $\sigma^2:1\mapsto 3$ and $\sigma^3 :1 \mapsto 4$, and so on. It seems quite trivial since every application of $\sigma$ simply maps the current symbol to the next, but I do not know how to write this out properly. Following this logic, then it seems that to have $k$ such that $\sigma^k : x\mapsto x $, $k$ must at least cause it to "loop around", i.e. $k$ has to be at least $r$. But if $k>r$, then it will "overshoot", and so $k=r$. Correct?

Comment: Hint:What happens when order is less then or greater to lenght.Derive contradiction in both cases and conclude equailty

Comment: not quite sure how to arrive at contradiction because I have no results I can use to rewrite the cycles into something else. I've given it more thought and I'm going to add them into my original post after this.

Comment: @VanioBegic, I've added in some thoughts in original post. Is that final line I wrote in the right direction of obtaining the contradictions?

Comment: Prove by induction over $i$ that $\sigma^i(j) \in \left\{ 1, 2, \ldots, r \right\}$ and $\sigma^i(j) \equiv i+j \mod r$ for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Would you like to put your comment as an answer. I'll upvote it.